# The "road-map" for when the IOTA Tangle reaches sufficient size?

Tags: transaction, iota-network, tangle, coordinator

Apparently we are still in "testnet" including a "coordinator" responsible for the validation of all transactions until the tangle reaches sufficient size. If so, what is the "road-map" on this point?

Comment: You should rephrase the question. Do you want to know when the main tangle reaches a sufficient size to turn off the coordinator? You should have this in your topic, since sufficient size can be anything

Comment: if so then there is already one topic here on this question: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-are-the-prerequisites-for-shutting-down-the-iota-coordinator

Answer (score 2):

IOTA is NOT on a testnet. It is on the mainnet. And the Coordinator does exist on the mainnet.

There is no official roadmap for the removal of the Coordinator AFAIK.

Comment: @Zass but according to this answer : [link](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-are-the-prerequisites-for-shutting-down-the-iota-coordinator) and this page : [link](https://blog.iota.org/the-transparency-compendium-26aa5bb8e260) , there is coordinator in IOTA, isn't it ? Thanks

Comment: Did I say there isn’t? In fact I said the opposite: there is indeed a coordinator on the mainnet.